# frame in NewDocumentEnvironment

Tags: beamer, macros, environments, xparse

With beamer frames, this does not work.

```
\newenvironment{itemframe}[1]{
  \begin{frame}{#1}
    \begin{itemize}
}{
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
}
```

Adding `fragile, environment=itemframe` as an optional argument to the frame will solve the issue. But there is also an alternative that avoids making the frame fragile: Exporting everything apart from the frame environments to own commands.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newenvironment{itemframe}[1]{
%\NewDocumentEnvironment{itemframe}{m}{
  \begin{frame}{#1}
    \itemframebegin
}{
    \itemframeend
  \end{frame}
}
\newcommand\itemframebegin{
  \begin{itemize}
}
\newcommand\itemframeend{
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemframe}{Title}
  \item A
  \item B
  \item C
\end{itemframe}
\end{document}
```

Now when `\newenvironment` is replaced with `\NewDocumentEnvironment` from the `xparse` package, as shown as a comment above, both solutions again fail with

```
! File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
```

Is there a possibility to make a `\NewDocumentEnvironment` including a `frame`? Avoiding the fragile option is preferred.

Comment: You can't have `\end{frame}` hidden in a macro.

Comment: I use variations of the second code block in many of my documents. So in an environment, it seems possible.

Comment: I replaced the second code block with a minimal working example to show that it is indeed possible.

Comment: Environments defined with `\NewDocumentEnvironment` seem to play bad with `\beamer@collect@@body`. But what's the gain in defining such an environment? I can't see any.

Comment: @egreg Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `xparse` defined environments play bad with `\beamer@collect@@body`.

A workaround is using `environ`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\NewEnviron{itemframe}{\expandafter\doitemframe\BODY\ENDBODY}
\NewDocumentCommand{\doitemframe}{mo u{\ENDBODY}}{%
  \begin{frame}{#1}
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{NO OPT}{OPT}
  \begin{itemize}
  #3
  \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemframe}{Title}[opt]
  \item A
  \item B
  \item C
\end{itemframe}
\end{document}
```

The argument list is ended by `u{\ENDBODY}` so that `\doitemframe` collects the arguments in the proper way and then you can use `#3` (or whatever is the resulting argument number).

If you don't need the full force of `xparse` but just standard arguments, you can do

```
\NewEnviron{itemframe}[1]{%
  \begin{frame}{#1}
  \begin{itemize}
  \BODY
  \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
}
```

With `xparse` release 2019-05-03 one can do as follows: `+b` denotes that the body of the environment will be collected (in this case as `#3`) before processing further.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{itemframe}{mo+b}
 {%
  \begin{frame}{#1}
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{NO OPT}{OPT: #2}
  \begin{itemize}
  #3
  \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
 }{}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemframe}{Title}[opt]
  \item A
  \item B
  \item C
\end{itemframe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both solutions do not work with fragile frames.

Comment: @stefanct Of course they don't, but the OP wanted exactly to avoid fragile frames.